# Where is "Reality is one, though wise men speak of it variously." in the Rig Veda?

Tags: rig-veda

In ["An Apology for Apologetics: A Study in the Logic of Interreligious Dialogue" by Paul J. Griffiths](https://books.google.com/books?id=7jRKAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA46#v=onepage&q&f=false), Paul writes the following:

> The Rigveda, India's oldest collection of sacred texts, contains the famous line: "Reality is one, though wise men speak of it variously."

Does anyone know the Book, Hymn and Verse this is from in the Rig Veda? I am assuming he either reworded another translation or translated this into English himself; as I am unable to find it in the translations I've looked at.

All search results I've found for that line all reference his book as the source and he does not cite the book, hymn and verse of it in his book. Is anyone familiar with where this is in the Rig Veda?

Comment: Welcome to HSE! You may accept [GIRIBLR's answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/48404/647)  as it was posted before Prayas Nagari's answer.

Comment: Did you remove the answer that was better structured and contained more information? I absolutely will not reward the answer to the less informative answer and your deletion of the better answer is unbelievable.

Comment: @BrettAllen To improve the formatting or structure of an answer, one should [edit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/48404/edit) the existing one rather than posting a duplicate. Though if another answer contains additional useful information, then we would keep it otherwise duplicate answer subject to deletion. (Refer 4th bullet from [Help-Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers))

Answer (score 6):

This is from Rig Veda 1.164.46.

> *ekaṁ sad viprā bahudhā vadanti*
>
> ekam: one
>
> sat: Reality
>
> vipra: wise
>
> bahuda: various ways
>
> vadanti: speak

There is one reality, the wise speak of it in various ways.